# What is probability to get two balls of different colors, if one of them is blue?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> There are $12$ red, $8$ green and $10$ blue balls in a box. Two balls are taken out at random. What is probability to get two balls of different colors, if one of them is blue?

We can use the formula of Conditional probability. Let $B=\{\text{got blue ball}\}$, $A = \{\text{two balls of different colors are taken}\}$.
$$P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(AB)}{P(B)}$$
$$P(B) = \frac{C^1_{10} \cdot C^1_{29}}{C^2_{30}}$$
$$P(AB)= \frac{C^1_{10} \cdot C^1_{20}}{C^2_{30}}$$
And answer is $20/29$. But it's wrong, and I don't understand why. Right is $40/49$.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by you denominator $C_{30}^1,$ but it seems wrong. The denominator should be $30\cdot 29.$ Also, $P(B)$ is wrong, because you have only counted the case when the first draw is blue, not when either draw is blue.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, it was a typo. I mean $C^2_{30}$. The order is not important to us. The pair of balls R + B = B+R

Comment: But then you are double-counting the case when both balls are blue. You are correct, there are $200$ ways to get a blue ball and a non-blue ball in that rule, but there are only $45$ ways to get two blue balls, and you've counted it as $90.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You computed the probability of obtaining at least one blue ball incorrectly.  For the favorable cases, you can have either two blue balls, which occurs with probability 
$$\Pr(\text{two blue}) = \frac{\dbinom{10}{2}}{\dbinom{30}{2}}$$
or one blue ball and one ball of a different color, which you correctly calculated is 
$$\Pr(\text{exactly one blue}) = \frac{\dbinom{10}{1}\dbinom{20}{1}}{\dbinom{30}{2}}$$
so the probability that at least one of the balls is blue is 
$$\Pr(\text{at least one blue}) = \frac{\dbinom{10}{2} + \dbinom{10}{1}\dbinom{20}{1}}{\dbinom{30}{2}}$$
Thus, the probability that two different balls of different colors are obtained if at least one blue ball is selected is
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\text{two balls of different colors} \mid \text{at least one blue selected}) & = \frac{\frac{\binom{10}{1}\binom{20}{1}}{\binom{30}{2}}}{\frac{\binom{10}{2} + \binom{10}{1}\binom{20}{1}}{\binom{30}{2}}}\\
& = \frac{\dbinom{10}{1}\dbinom{20}{1}}{\dbinom{10}{2} + \dbinom{10}{1}\dbinom{20}{1}}
\end{align*}

In your attempt to calculate $\Pr(\text{at least one blue})$, you selected a blue ball and one of the remaining balls.  Doing so counts each selection with $2$ blue balls twice, once for each way you could designate one of the blue balls as the blue ball you have chosen.  Observe that 
$$\color{red}{\binom{2}{1}}\binom{10}{2} + \binom{10}{1}\binom{20}{1} = \color{red}{\binom{10}{1}\binom{29}{1}}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys! I am so stupid sometimes ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your setup for the calculation of $P(AB)$ agrees with mine, but $P(B)$ is incorrect.

Note that when both balls are blue, you have counted the pair in two different ways. For example, the balls picked by $\binom{10}{1}$ and  $\binom{29}{1}$ can be blue number $1$ and $2$ respectively or number $2$ and $1$ respectively.

This cannot be fixed simply by applying a factor, since the pairs that are not both blue are not duplicated.

You could work out the case of two blue balls  separately from the case of exactly one blue ball, then add them. 
But I think the simplest approach is to subtract the cases where neither ball is blue from the total. That is, the number of ways you can choose at least one blue ball is
$$ \binom{30}{2} - \binom{20}{2}. $$

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys! I am so stupid sometimes ;)